# Trying to assign return type as void

Tags: c#, .net

`Func<int, void>` or  `Func<int, typeof(void)>` seems to be not working.

Is it any way to solve this problem without delcaring custom delegates?

Comment: By the way, `typeof(`*anything*`)` will never work in a type argument list, as it returns a `Type` object; it's not a type itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

void is not a data type in C#. You could use:

`Action<int>`

which is a delegate type for a method with a single int parameter and no return value.

Comment: C# void is an alias for the .NET Framework System.Void type.
System.Void is a structure that specifies a return value type for a method that does not return a value.

Comment: System.Void is only useful if you're using reflection. It's not a real type, rather a placeholder to indicate "no return type"

Comment: Is it really not a real type? I know for sure `void` is a real type in the Common Type System, but it might not be the same as `System.Void`.

Comment: It depends what you call a real type. It would be interesting to see if you could define a variable of type void in the CLR. I doubt it though.

Comment: You cannot. Void is only usable as a return type. See my recent article on this for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/29/the-void-is-invariant.aspx